# Get conda environment path from env name

Tags: batch-file, findstr

Hi I'm trying to get the path of a conda env from its name:

```
conda info --envs
```

I get:

```
base                     C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3
RPDA                  *  C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\envs\RPDA
test310                  C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\envs\test310
RPDA2                    C:\Users\u608771\.conda\envs\RPDA2
```

so if I do

```
conda info --envs | findstr /c:"RPDA"
```

I get:

```
RPDA                  *  C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\envs\RPDA
RPDA2                    C:\Users\u608771\.conda\envs\RPDA2
```

how can i get just the path(neglecting the "*" if present)?: C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\envs\RPDA

and how can i assign it to a variable, something like:

```
set envpath=conda info --envs | findstr /c:"RPDA"
```

Comment: There could be used `for /F "tokens=1* delims=*  " %%I in ('conda info --envs ^| %SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /R "^RPDA\>"') do set "envpath=%%J"` with an asterisk, a horizontal tab and a normal space as the three delimiters. Please open a [command prompt](https://www.howtogeek.com/235101/), run `findstr /?` and read the output usage help and next `for /?` and read again the output usage help from top of first to bottom of last page. I recommend to use above this line `set "envpath="` and below this line `if not defined envpath echo Failed to get path of environment RPDA.& pause`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you are only interested in the item with the `*` and it appares only once in the request:

As commandline:

```
for /f "usebackq tokens=1,2,*" %a in (`conda info --envs ^| findstr /c:"*"`) do @set envpath=%c

echo %envpath%
```

In a batch script you have to double the `%a`  =>  `%%a`

```
@echo off
for /f "usebackq tokens=1,2,*" %%a in (`conda info --envs ^| findstr /c:"*"`) do @set envpath=%%c
```

---

Edit: As you opt to keep all lines for the pattern 'RPDA, here an extended solution that takes the names in the first column as part of the variable name:

```
@echo off
for /f "usebackq tokens=1,* delims= * " %%i in (
    `conda info --envs ^| findstr /b /c:"RPDA"`
) do @(
    set RESULT_%%i=%%j
)
```

To see the result type

```
set "RESULT_"
```

---

*Edit: Evaluated some of user Mofi's suggestions and simplified the code.*

Comment: Hi thanks, for your answer. no actually i'm interested in any environment that i could pass in the string

Comment: why do you use %a for the loop but %c for set the variable?, sorry but my knowledge of batch is very limited

Comment: `tokens=1,2,*` assigns the variables in alphabetical order, starting with the first one given (here %a, but any other would do it too) . The `*` as 3rd in `tokens=1,2,*` takes the rest of the line and will be stored in %c  (as the 3rd letter counting form  %a)

Comment: If you wish to store all entries you also need more variables to store the content. I assumed %envpath% is a unique required name for the environment variable.

Comment: Updated  the answer with a solution that assigns all lines found to a variable named in dependence of the result.

Comment: @Alberto B Has your problem been solved?

Comment: Yes I finally went for this:
```set "EnvPath="```
 
```for /f "usebackq tokens=1,* delims=* " %%a in (`conda info --envs ^| findstr /R /c:"%EnvName%\>"`) do set EnvPath=%%b```